# Sigma sign issue

Tags: summation

In the answer key to one of the problems, the following step takes place

$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(a_kx^2-2x+\frac{1}{a_k}\right)=(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)x^2-2nx+\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+...+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)$

Why does $\sum_{k=1}^n2x=2nx$ not just $2x$ because isn't there no $k$ to apply the sign onto?

Comment: Please write out your steps using MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: how can someone on 430 points not bother to use mathjax?

Comment: @jimjim Can you answer the question now?

Comment: David already has, take my upvote instead , thank you for making the question better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n2x = \underbrace{2x + 2x + 2x + \cdots + 2x}_{\text{$n$ times}}.
$$